# How do I create string of random length using different calls to random in PL/SQL Oracle Developer?

Tags: oracle, random

I am writing a chunk of PL/Code to test a database for a homework assignment. The criteria for what I am working on: b. Email must be less than 20 characters long, and must be a valid format, e.g. having a ‘@’ sign and a ‘.’ sign at the right position.

So I will have a string/varchar that is less than 20. I know that with the Top Level Domain as 3 spaces, the dot, and the at symbol taking up 5 spaces of that length, which leaves 14 spaces. So I thought I could randomly generate a string in the range of 1-14 to fill in the remaining spaces, and make the whole thing less than 20. How would I do this?

```
Email := dmbs_random.string('U', trunc(dbms_random.value(1,14))||'@'||dmbs_random.string('U', trunc(dbms_random.value(1,14))||'.'||dbms_random.string('U',3)<20;
```

I know the above is incorrect, but it is just psuedo code of what I am attempting.

Comment: You are almost there. Use CEIL instead of TRUNC (otherwise 0.24 becomes 0 and you will generate a string of length 0, which is illegal for emails). Why not generate a first portion of length between 2 and 10, the second portion of length between 3 and 7, and the last one of length exactly 3? If it's just for testing, that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

See my Comment under the original post for a brief explanation. The first and second part should be up to 9 and 6 characters respectively (we only have room for 15 characters, not 17 - I was counting the third part of the address, but I didn't count the "at" and the "period").

```
select     dbms_random.string('U', ceil(dbms_random.value(1.01, 9))) || '@' ||
           dbms_random.string('U', ceil(dbms_random.value(2.01, 6))) || '.' ||
           dbms_random.string('U', 3) as email
from       dual
connect by level <= 5
;

EMAIL
-------------------
VN@DUCZ.OQD
KTXNQWEL@PJITFC.ZAR
CHDTR@LMOXAO.WCD
GNV@LVTRU.AQG
LLC@TWJBB.NWT
```